# Are action names part of the public API in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure what is the `@@` prefix in the actions which most third-party packages I've installed in my React/Redux app mean -- if they mean "private", then the answer to my question is obvious. I see them in the Redux devtools extension for Chrome.

In case it's just a scoping convention `@@<package>/<action>`, then I have a concrete question regarding actions in `redux-form` package. Actions are, apparently, [not documented](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/), so I'm **not sure if I can safely use them in *my* reducers** without worrying for breaking changes.

For more context in case my approach is completely wrong (still figuring out patterns): I want to remove the register form and present a success message after successful completion. `redux-form` dispatches an action of type `@@redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED`, with `meta.form` telling me that it was a form I named `register`. So I'd use it in my `RegisterPage` reducer to set a boolean `isSuccess` and use that to change the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are not explicitly documented I would consider them private and not use them directly. Even though it's not stated officially anywhere, the `@@` prefix often indicates private actions which shouldn't be handled by other reducer code. I think it originated from the `@@redux/INIT_{random string}` action (discussion about the naming can be found in this [github thread](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/186)):

> In the new docs (#140) we should clarify that any actions prefixed
>   with @@ are not meant to be handled. For example, you should never try
>   to handle @@INIT.

In the [redux code itself](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/actionTypes.js) the privateness is also explicitly stated:

```
/**
 * These are private action types reserved by Redux.
 * For any unknown actions, you must return the current state.
 * If the current state is undefined, you must return the initial state.
 * Do not reference these action types directly in your code.
 */
```

For your specific problem: you could provide a [onSubmitSuccess function](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmitsuccess-function-code-optional-) to the HOC and dispatch your own action to update your own reducer or you could directly depend on the redux form state and get this boolean flag via the [hasSubmitSucceeded selector](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/#-code-hassubmitsucceeded-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-gt-submitsucceeded-boolean-code-). Personally I think the second option is the better one because it doesn't introduce redundant state in your store - redux form already stores the information whether a form was submitted successfully, doing so on your own in another sub-reducer could lead to the two boolean values diverging unintentionally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "and dispatch your own action to update your own reducer" -- I was thinking that I should avoid that in order to leverage the fact that an action is propagated across the whole store (and not tie an action with a specific part of store). It seemed to me that firing an action because another action fired is exactly what Redux is try to solve (a mess of events which trigger other events), but seems like third-party reducers play against this.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović strictly speaking, you are not firing an action because of another action but firing two actions for the same user event. But of course you are right, this is also a form of redundancy. The second option (simply using the value redux-form provides via the already prepared selector hasSubmitSucceeded) is definitely preferable.

Comment: The redux FAQ doesn't strictly prohibit the dispatch of [multiple actions in a row](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#should-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-a-row-from-one-action-creator). Avoid it if you can, but there are legitimate cases

Comment: Great advices. Thanks!